# How to use the HTML Tidy .NET DLL wrapper in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, htmltidy

I'm trying to use the [HTML Tidy .NET wrapper](http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy.html#dotnet) in PowerShell 2.0.

Here is a working example using C# (TestIt.cs included in the wrapper distribution):

```
using Tidy;
Document tdoc = new Document();
```

I'm doing this in PowerShell:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\e-t172\Desktop\Tidy.NET\Tidy.dll")
New-Object Tidy.Document
```

I get the following error:

```
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Tidy.Document.
At line:1 char:11
+ New-Object <<<<  Tidy.Document
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Additional info:

```
> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\e-t172\Desktop\Tidy.NET\Tidy.dll").getTypes()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ITidyDocumentEvents
True     True     TidyReportLevel                          System.Enum
True     True     __MIDL_ITidyDocument_0008                System.Enum
True     False    DocumentClass                            System.__ComObject
True     False    ITidyDocumentEvents_Event
True     True     ITidyDocumentEvents_OnMessageEventHan... System.MulticastDelegate
True     False    Document
True     False    ITidyDocument
True     True     TidyOptionId                             System.Enum
True     True     __MIDL_ITidyDocument_0002                System.Enum
False    False    ITidyDocumentEvents_SinkHelper           System.Object
False    False    ITidyDocumentEvents_EventProvider        System.Object
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating the document using the DocumentClass type e.g.:

```
$doc = new-object tidy.documentclass
```

C# does some magic when using interop assemblies and IIRC one of those is to take a class spec of "Foo" and in turn create an instance of "FooClass".

Comment: At first I thought this didn't work... then I realized I was trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit Powershell session... I switched to a 32-bit PowerShell session and it works!